# Inject dependency associated with Listener action

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

What is the best way to inject dependency, connected with Listener action?

For ex. I want to use event track, when user clicks on spinner row.

```
public SimpleListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Inject
AnalyticsHelper analyticsHelper; // thats look awful inside listener

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, 
 int position, long id) {
...
}
```

Thanks